# Can I clean-install iOS 11 on my iPhone 7?

Tags: install, iphone

My iPhone 7 is too buggy since I upgraded it to the iOS 11 beta. Now the iOS 11 had finally been released for a while, but my iPhone, even after upgraded to the official release, still too buggy (while using an app, the screen suddently got freezed and it is not responsive for a few minutes; an app didn't launch sometimes and crash immediately; etc...).

I already cleaned all my data and settings, and restored it from my backup, but it didn't resolve the issue.

So I would rather like to clean-install it. Is it possible to do that in iPhone?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

Comment: @ReneLarsen I already restored but it still got freezed. So I want to clean install it.

Comment: A restore without applying a backup afterwards is a clean install - and the same applies if you download an .ipsw file first and then use this file to do the restore (the automatic restore from iTunes also download the same .ipsw file)

Comment: @ReneLarsen So are the restroing the contents on iPhone and restaring it on iTunes not the same?

Comment: Yes if you do a `General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings` it should be the same.

Comment: @ReneLarsen But does it not download ipsw file?

Comment: It will do a restore - which size the downloaded image file is - I don’t know - probably it is a full size image. Remember to do take a backup to iCloud or iTunes first - just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Download the latest .ipsw file for your device. I get my stuff from Redmond Pie. I prefer clean installs as well. The .ipsw file is around 2-2.6 GB.